# How do I get task scheduler to run my batch file minimized

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there a way to have the task scheduler run my batch file minimized. I thought I could do something like the following but does not work. I tried without those quotes as well.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Program/script:** `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe`

**Add arguments:** `/C start "" /MIN C:\temp\keepwarm.bat`

For explanation, read about [(internal) START command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) or run `start /?` from an open command prompt.

Note: if the (minimized) window stays open after the bat script ends then use

*Add arguments:* `/C "start "" /MIN C:\temp\keepwarm.bat ^&exit"`

(take heed of a space between path to script and `^&exit` - edited due to [*Viktor Liashenko*'s useful comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1545718/how-do-i-get-task-scheduler-to-run-my-batch-file-minimized/1545723?noredirect=1#comment2753697_1545723)).

You can enclose path to script in a pair of double quotes as follows:

*Add arguments:* `/C "start "" /MIN "C:\temp\keepwarm.bat" ^&exit"`

This solves problem of space(s) in path to script…

Comment: In my case when the path has space symbols, I've added "EXIT" command to the end of my script. And it works well. Thanks!
Path with spaces I've enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: Although, if I write:
/C start "" /MIN "C:\_My files\CmdBAT\Tasks\Restart_thunderbird.bat" ^& exit
it works well too.
If I write this command without space after quotation mark, it doesn't work:
/C start "" /MIN "C:\_My files\CmdBAT\Tasks\Restart_thunderbird.bat"^& exit